# Browserrouting only running when displaying App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I build a website in react with Browserrouting and have the following code & issue

```
 const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
 root.render(
<React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<App/>}>
                <Route path="/home" element={<Homepage />} />
```

The Problem I have is when i run the App it opens the "App" and not the actual Homepage.
I tried to fix it by changing change the App to Homepage but it is not working.
In my understanding /   needs to be there so the App displays in any other Path and is functioning.

Can some explain me, how i can make the path / still the Homepage without having to type /home to get there?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are rendering the `Homepage` in a nested route that is rendering `App`. In this configuration `<Route path="/" element={<App />}>` is what is called a [Layout Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes). `App` will be rendered when the path is exactly `"/"` and should render an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/outlet) component for the nested routes to render their content to.

An issue I see here, and you should have been seeing a `react-router-dom` invariant error regarding nesting an absolute path within a route rendering on an absolute path. In other words, `"/home"` is an absolute path and ***can't*** be nested under the absolute path `"/"`; it's not reachable.

If `App` really is a layout route and you *always* want it to render then you could remove the `path` prop from the parent route rendering `App`, and move `Homepage` to `"/"`.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<App />}>
      <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BowserRouter>
```

or convert `Homepage` into an `index` route and leave the `"/"` path on the parent layout route so the relative routing can still work properly and `Homepage` is rendered on `"/"`.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
      <Route index element={<Homepage />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BowserRouter>
```

I should point out that this is a slightly abnormal configuration. Typically the `App` component would render the `Routes` and `Route` components instead of an `Outlet` and it's assumed to all render on `"/"` by default. The `Homepage` component would then be rendered on `path="/"`.

Example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BowserRouter>
```

...

```
const App = () => {
  .... app logic ....

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

There is OFC, the chance here that you didn't intend to nest these routes and want them to be matched and rendered independently. In this case the solution is to just unnest the `Homepage` route and continue using absolute paths for the root routes.

Example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
    <Route path="/home" element={<Homepage />} />
  </Routes>
</BowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue

I had to

```
 <Route path="" element={<App/>}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
```

Delete the Path / in App and only add Path / in Homepage.

It works now